# I'm trying to count the value int in the java linked list Without success

Tags: java, linked-list

I've tried to count the numbers of int in linked list, but it's didn't work.
I really glad to your help.

```
public class Node {                 
    public int  data;                 
    public Node next;                 
    public Node (int data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;               
    }  

    public Node (int data) {          
        this(data,null);                
    }                                 
}

public static int occurrences (int value, Node intNode) {
    int counter =0 ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < intNode.lenght ; i++)
    {
        if (i == intNode[i])
        {
             counter++
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: One good way to ask a question that gets better replies is to try and create a [mcve]. It can really help get trivial errors of your code out of the way.

Comment: _it's didn't work._ Can you elaborate?

Comment: what are you trying to count?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the point of the value parameter? You don't use it anywhere. I think you meant to say:

`if (value == intNode.data)`

2. Also you are returning counter before the loop is over... thus you only ever run the for loop one time. You need return counter to be the last statement in the method, so put it after the for loop.
3. intNode is not an array. It is a Node object. The Node object doesn't have a field called length. Therefore you cannot say intNode.length in the for loop conditions.
4. Since intNode is not an array, and just an object of type Node, I'm not sure why you are writing intNode[i] . You can't get the ith element of something that isn't an array, and just an object.

You need to declare something like:

`Node curNode = intNode`

For your loop, you want to loop until you hit the end of your linked list, which would be when the currNode is null. So your loop would start:

`while (currNode != null)`

Then, at the end of each iteration of the loop, you want to move onto the next node. Move onto the next node like so:

`currNode = currNode.next`

Once currNode becomes null, the loop will stop and you will return counter.

I think you should study up more on linked list. See help here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-in-java/